# Marque progress timer for windows 7 phone

Tags: progress-bar, windows-phone-7

I am wondering if the windows 7 phone sdk comes with a marque progress bar? As far I can tell is that there is no marque styles so at the moment i just have a timer that updates the progress bar to emulate the style.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although the phone UI guidelines dictate a specific "progress indicator" control as well, the ProgressBar with IsIndeterminate is nearly equivalent minus the text.

Do note that the standard ProgressBar built into the platform has a negative effect on the UI thread's frame rate and should not be used.

Not that I want to self-promote, but I've published a template that can be used to move the exact same animation from the UI to the render thread in your application, significantly improving performance.

We wanted to find a way to get it into the release but it wasn't easy given the lack of size-relative declarative animations in Silverlight.

http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2010/08/performanceprogressbar/

Also, note that when you no longer need the animation, on top of collapsing the visual if you need to, please set IsIndeterminate to False to stop any storyboards that are running.

Comment: Yea, definitely recommend check out Jeff's work on pushing progress bar onto the render thread. I should have mentioned it myself. This is good stuff.

Answer (score 0):

The IsIndeterminate property is your ticket for a ProgressBar with no indication of when completion will occur.